# Making multiple subplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am very new to R and struggling with something that I know should be simple. I am able to make one scatterplot but would like to make multiple subplots using each feature in my dataset plotted against the variable: per_gop.

My code for one scatter plot is as follows:

```
data_US@data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(Hispanic_o), y=as.numeric(per_gop)))+ 
  geom_point(aes(fill=as.numeric(gop_dem), size=as.numeric(total_vote)),colour="#525252",pch=21) +
  stat_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=1, colour="#525252")+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="RdBu", type="div", direction=1, guide="colourbar", limits=c(-1,1))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  ggtitle(paste("correlation:",round(cor.test(as.numeric(data_US@data$per_gop),as.numeric(data_US@data$Hispanic_o))$estimate,2)))
```

I have tried using a gather function for this but I am not sure how to correctly  pass it to the code for plotting:

My code so far for multiple subplots is as follows:

```
data_US@data %>%

  gather(c(White_alon,Black_or_A, Asian_alon,Hispanic_o,Foreign_bo,
          Veterans_2,Language_o,Homeowners,Median_val,Per_capita,Bachelors_,
          Private_no), key = "expl_var", value="la_prop") %>%

  ggplot(aes(x=??????, y=per_gop))+ 
  geom_point(aes(fill=gop_dem, size=total_vote),colour="#525252",pch=21) +
  stat_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=1, colour="#525252")+
  scale_fill_distiller("BrBG", type="div", direction=1, guide="colourbar", limits=c(-1,1))+
  facet_wrap(~expl_var, scales="free")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="none")+ggtitle(paste("correlation:",round(cor.test(data_US@data$per_gop,data_US@data$Persons_65)$estimate,2)))
```

This is the style of output I am trying to create, just without the repeating variable:

[image]

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction... Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Have you looked at `?ggpairs` ?

Comment: Have you looked at `?melt`? If you melted those attributes you `gather()` from wide-form to long-form, you could use `?ggplot2::facet_wrap` or `?ggplot2::facet_grid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset. Should be possible to apply same form to your data, but hard to know for sure without seeing an example of that data.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  gather(expl_var, la_prop, -mpg) %>%
  ggplot(aes(la_prop, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(colour="#525252",pch=21) +
  stat_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, size=1, colour="#525252")+
  facet_wrap(~expl_var, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the direction I needed!